# Full path name to a file and separate files from directory

Tags: c

I am creating a program that read files. So far I have managed to let the user enter a filename and then the program will search for it in a directory, which was also entered by the user. But I have 2 problems.

How do I get the full path name to the file I just found and how do separate the files in the directory from each other, because I want the user to be able to enter if he wants directories or just files.

This is a part of the code:

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "b:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'b':
            cValue = optarg;
            if(*cValue == 'd')
            {
                int i;
                int a = 0;
                if(argc >= 3)
                {
                    for(i = optind; i < argc - 1; i++)
                    {
                        pDir = opendir(argv[i]);
                        if (pDir == NULL)
                        {
                            printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", argv[i]);
                            return 1;
                        }

                        while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
                        {
                            if(strcmp(pDirent->d_name, argv[argc - 1]) == 0)
                            {
                                printf ("[%s]\n", pDirent->d_name);
                            }
                        }
                        closedir (pDir);
                        a++;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            abort();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

to get the current work directory. With `strncpy`, you can get the full path of these files.